# Got An Error: firestore.setListeners is not a function. while integrating redux-firestore with react-redux-firebase@2.0.*

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga, react-redux-firebase

> Blockquote

PHOTO(Click here to see the Error) : Got An Error: firestore.setListeners is not a function

> Blockquote

I have just integrated redux-saga, redux-firestore with react-redux-firebase@2.*.* and its working fine but when i try to integrate with other COMPONENT i got This Error.. 
ANY SOLUTION!! 
THANKS

[This is the error white integrating redux-firestore with react-reduc-firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPFeJ.png)

Code:

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import { getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import {
  firestoreConnect,
  createWithFirebase,
  withFirebase,
  firebaseConnect
} from 'react-redux-firebase'

*******
**etc**
*******

// export default Inventory;
export default compose(
// firestoreConnect([{collection: 'Invetory'}]),
  firebaseConnect(),
  connect(
    ({ firestore }) => ({
      //todos: firestore.ordered.todos,
      firestore
    })
  )
  // connect((state) => ({
  //   auth: state.firestore.auth
  // })
)(Inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Author of react-redux-firebase here.

Looks like you may not have included importing Firestore [as mentioned in the Firestore section of the react-redux-firebase docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html). Make sure you include the enhancer, the reducer, and import firestore from Firebase like so:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore' // add this to use Firestore
import { reactReduxFirebase, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { reduxFirestore, firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {}

// react-redux-firebase config
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  // useFirestoreForProfile: true // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
}

// initialize firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) // <- new to v2.*.*

// initialize Firestore
firebase.firestore()

// Add reduxReduxFirebase and reduxFirestore enhancers when making store creator
const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(
  reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
  reduxFirestore(firebase)
)(createStore)

// Add Firebase and Firestore to reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseStateReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer
})

// Create store with reducers and initial state
const initialState = {}
const store = createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer, initialState)
```

Comment: thank you, the import "firebase/firestore" was needed and i didnt know that.